Как в декораторе оформить аннотацию возвращаемого класса со сгенерированными в этом декораторе атрибутами
Есть декарированный класс Entity_1 с атрибутом класса attrs, содержащим список элементов класса Attr
Декоратор меняет исходный класс на новый с заменой attrs со списком на attrs-объект с набором атрибутов из этого списка.
Все работает. Но хочется на ходу получать нормально аннотированный класс Entity_1. Сейчас IDE не видит атрибуты attrs.
Как правильно переписать декоратор?
from typing import Any, List

class Attr:
    def __init__(self, name: str, title: str = None, value: Any = None):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.value = value

class Entity:
    attrs: List[Attr]

def entity(EntityClass: Entity):
    class Attrs:
        pass

    for attr in EntityClass.attrs:
        setattr(Attrs, attr.name, attr)

    class WrapEntityClass():
        attrs: Attrs = Attrs()

    return WrapEntityClass

@entity
class Entity_1(Entity):
    attrs: List[Attr] = [
       Attr(name='id', title='Title1', value=111),
       Attr(name='name', title='Title2', value='Name1'),
       Attr(name='note', title='Title3', value='Note1')
    ]

e1 = Entity_1()
print(e1.attrs.id.name, e1.attrs.id.title, e1.attrs.id.value)

Вроде, я понял, что нужно как-то сгенерировать аннотацию для нового класса и вернуть из декоратора. Не понимаю как и в каком месте это сделать практически.

Никак, ide не сможет увидеть генерируемые в рантайме атрибуты

Я бы пошел от обратного: объявлять атрибуты в классе обычным способом (типа id: Attr), по ним уже значения инициализировать. Можно использовать typing.Annotated, который сейчас рекомендуют использовать в том же pydantic вместо старого способа декларации через Field, по аннотации потом в декораторе поля инициализировать как вам нужно.
